# WUFTP: sleeping: fcntl lock of pid file failed: Permission denied

Tags: ftp, unix

Our main and largest FTP server, which uses wuftpd as FTP server software is facing constant drops of connection. It has been running for years now, all of suddenly, is presenting this problem.

Searching the logs I found out this entry: 
"daemon:err|error ftpd[9306438]: sleeping: fcntl lock of pid file failed: Permission denied"

I google'd it and there is not much information about this.

Does anyone knows what this error is about and if it would be related to my current connection-drop problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep investigation, it was found my problem was a reflex of a memory shortage in the F5 LoadBalancers of our Brocade switches. This was not a problem in the OS, FTP, settings whatsoever.

If you have a problem similar to mine, I suggest you to get your  switches analyzed.